# Products folder is missed in Xcode (macOS)

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, product

When I create a new project in Xcode(macOS), there is no "products" folder in my project,
Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 13 new projects no longer show a Products folder in the project navigator. The workaround is to choose Product > Show Build Folder in Finder. Showing the build folder in the Finder shows the Products folder in the Finder.